# PHP Multiple value in 1 string

Tags: php

I have php script like this

```
<?php
$listkey = "aaa";
$apikey = $_GET['apikey'];
    if ($apikey == $listkey) {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["respon"] = "Success";
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["respon"] = "Failed";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

as you can see, the $ listkey data has one value, and I want the $ listkey data to have more than 2 values, I've tried using an array like this.

```
$listkey = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
```

but if I try it, the response I get is FAILED, even though I have included GET apikey = aaa or bbb is there any suitable suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to compare a string with values inside an array, that's not how it works. I'm assuming the value of `$apikey` will be a string, is that correct?

Comment: You want `in_array()` instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just found out, thanks in advance, but is there any suggestion from you to create multiple values in a single string?

Comment: Why does error = true when you have a successful match and error = false when there is no match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in_array() method, below example is useful to you.

```
<?php
 $listkey = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");
 if (in_array($apikey,  $listkey))
 {
   echo "Match found";
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Match not found";
 }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, finally this script goes according to my wish :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($apikey == $listkey) {
```

That's why it won't work, you are trying to compare a string with an array. You can either use an iteration, or an in_array() PHP function.

```
if ( in_array($apikey,$listkey) ) {
```

The latter one seems simplier, it checks if the $listkey array contains a value that equals to the $apikey string.

You might need to add a third parameter "true" to the in_array, as in non-strict cases the function might return as a false true.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I'm curious about the downvotes, this would seem to do what the OP wants if I understand the question correctly...

Comment: I'm weirded out too, I just posted it, and got -2 in less than 3 seconds...

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. The **square brackets** from the `[, bool $strict = FALSE ]` notation you have found in the [documentation of `in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) means the argument (together with the comma in front of it) is optional; they are just a notation used in the documentation, they must not appear in the code. Also, the `= false` part specify the default value of the argument (when it is not present).

Comment: I just wanted to note he might need to set it true to work properly. Leaving it on false can lead to some true return value in the weirdest cases.

Comment: Make sure the code is valid PHP. Put the remarks as comments in the code or as plain text in the answer. The correct way to use `in_array()` with 3 arguments is `in_array($apikey, $listkey, true)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `in_array()`, see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
<?php
$listkey = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
$apikey = $_GET['apikey'];

if (in_array($apikey, $listkey) {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["respon"] = "Success";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["respon"] = "Failed";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in_Array concept

Please check the below code:

```
 <?php
 // $listkey = "aaa";
 $listkey = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");

 $_GET['apikey'] = "aaa";


 if (in_array($_GET['apikey'], $listkey))
 {
   $response["error"] = TRUE;
   $response["respon"] = "Success";
   echo json_encode($response);
 }
 else
 {
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["respon"] = "Failed";
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
```

This will helpful for you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to compare the string to an array. You can't just do it like:

```
if($string == $array)
```

that will cause errors.

You could iterate over your array to make the check worthwile;

```
$matched = false;
//Iterate over array
foreach($listkey as $key){
  if($key == $apikey){
    $matched = true; //Set match to true
    break; //Stop looping as it's not necessary
  }
}

if ($matched) {
  $response["error"] = TRUE;
  $response["respon"] = "Success";
  echo json_encode($response);
} else {
  $response["error"] = FALSE;
  $response["respon"] = "Failed";
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

-- You could also use `in_array()` (there are already answers for it) which would keep your code a bit more neat. However, it is a little bit less efficient. If it's a small array, it won't really make a big difference, though.